# What happened first: Agent Carter or One Shot?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agent-carter

So, having watched the series Agent Carter, this show is taking place 1 year after the events of the Captain America. Now, if you watched the Marvel One Shot of the same title, those events also take place 1 year later. Yet, at the end, they mention SHIELD and the fact that Carter/Howard are going to be running it. So, chronologically, whats going on here? Did they dismiss the One Shot?

Comment: Doesn't Agent Carter happen one year after the events of *Captain America: The First Avenger* and not after the Avengers movie?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the series creators:

> The show would start in 1946, sort of in the middle of the timeline of the One Shot.  McFeely said, “We can’t get her to the end of S.H.I.E.L.D. that fast.  We wanna stay in that world longer where people are disrespecting her and she’s proving herself and going on missions and things like that.” [(source)](http://collider.com/agent-carter-tv-series-christopher-markus-stephen-mcfeely/)

---

There is one bit of discontinuity with that timeline, however. In the one-shot, Carter works for an agent named John Flynn, head of the S.S.R. However, for the entire duration of Season One, Carter works for S.S.R. Chief Roger Dooley, and no mention is made of Flynn.

Without inventing some excuse for why Flynn never appears on-screen, it seems difficult to reconcile the two as happening simultaneously.

It would have made more sense, however, if the short took place immediately *after* the TV series Season 1, for several reasons.

First, during the one-shot, Flynn refuses to send Carter into the field, but does utilize her for her codebreaking skills. However, in one of the later episodes in Season One, the SSR brings in an outside crypt-analyst to break a Russian code, and Chief Dooley seems taken aback when Carter is able to crack it herself. That implies that she has *not* (yet) spent any significant time as a code breaker for the SSR.

Second,

> Dooley dies in the season finale, leaving an opening for Flynn to come in and take over.

And finally, as Season 1 wraps up,

> Peggy is unsure if she's going to remain at the SSR, putting her in the perfect position to be recruited by Stark for SHIELD.

Comment: Well, they could just "bring him in" from another branch or something. It's not really that far fetched of an idea, actually. Well done. I guess I was thinking the same, just wanted to have someone else put it to words for me. I am glad the show is going for season 2 now.

Comment: my point was that Carter took orders directly from Flynn for the entire duration of the One-Shot. If the TV show happened *in the middle* of the short film, it doesn't make sense that someone else is Carter's boss for the show and Flynn is never seen.

Comment: By "The show", they probably mean the entire run. If the show lasts 4 seasons and Flynn is the new boss in Season 2, then sure - the one-shot could easily take place during the events of the show.

Comment: Of course, season 2 happened, and look where that got us...

Answer (score 4):

The show takes place first, followed closely by the short.

IGN asked showrunner Michele Fazekas about this:

> IGN: How will that work with the short, because I think I’ve heard it kind of takes place in between? Does the short still exist, or are you going to be telling a new version of that?
>
> Fazekas: If you think of the short as sort of the end of the series, the series would be leading up to that moment where she gets assigned to SHIELD. [(Source)](http://www.ign.com/articles/2014/07/16/marvels-agent-carter-will-show-peggys-road-to-shield)

This is consistent with the details of the show and the short. In many ways, the events of the show appear an impetus to Stark Sr. to evaluate the SSR's shortcomings and start thinking about replacing it.

The "One Year Later" and "1946" tags in the short and show, respectively, are not such a huge problem. Less than a month elapses in the show - the short could easily follow the show without pushing it into 1947.

All this may change if Marvel decides they want another season of Agent Carter, and they want it to take place before SHIELD is founded. They will be very careful about retconning an expensive short, though, so that's unlikely.

Although it doesn't always tell you the evidence for its claims, [this timeline](http://www.thecomicboard.com/forum/showthread.php?13339-Marvel-Cinematic-Universe-Timeline) is an awesome resource for the chronology of the MCU.

Comment: Well, it did get picked up for a second season. So, we'll see what happens.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Source? I had not heard that.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most likely answer is that it was set after Captain America : The First Avenger and before the two seasons of Agent Carter. Due to a file in the one shot showing the date and the first episode of the second season displaying on the screen that it is set in 1947, it makes more sense than it being between the two seasons. Howard probably launched the idea of S.H.I.E.L.D to her after the one-shot, as we saw begin to happen at the end of it. However, he then was a suspected traitor, so the project was not launched and by the time his name was cleared, Peggy was busy with the SSR.

Answer (score 1):

I had been asking myself this same question. The comments really helped me piece it together, but I noticed a few other things. The one shot takes place first and then the show happens. As mentioned by someone else, the one shot starts on 3/15/46. Due to the allegations of Howard being a traitor, they never got around to talking about SHIELD and Peggy returned to the SSR. In the first episode of the show, the newspaper Peggy is reading in the beginning of the episode shows the date of 4/21/46 (one month after) and when she goes into the dinner after the office she’s seen reading a newspaper from 6/23/46 (3 months after). I think she was reading an old newspaper in her apartment and the show starts in June. Additionally, one of her flashbacks in the beginning of the episode shows a clip from the fight in the one shot (when she kicks one man through a window).

As for the discrepancy of the boss, Peggy was probably transferred to another branch because the office doesn’t look the same or some changes happened between March 46 to June 46.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an interesting interpretation of this matter. The film and series are set in different time lines, thus both are correct. If one pays close attention to the One Shot, two lines stand out to support this hypothesis.
First: The film is set one year after the events of Captain America, yet Agent Carter says it’s been 3 months since she’s been there. Hence this would place this situation around March of 46, roughly a month before the series by way of the paper in the series being dated April 29.
Second: Stark phones Flynn the next day to inform Carter she’s be running S.H.I.E.L.D. Again in March of 46 and before the series.
Based upon this deduction, one could surmise, the movies with Carter are based upon this timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine it this way. After season 2, Carter gets reassigned to New York... With the untimely death of Jack, they needed good agents. She returns to agent Flynn, who is now in charge after the untimely death of Jack. She re-enters back into the sexist world of male agents, who have heard about her but are threatened by her... she and her talent again are suppressed, so she goes again on a mission to prove herself... Flynn is moments from punishing her, and just then Howard calls and rescues her.

Thus, season 1-2 happens immediately after Captain America, the one shot happens immediately after season 2.

Answer (score 0):

The One Shot Agent Carter Starts off on exactly 3/15/46.
She gives a fellow agent a file of analysis on recent transmissions dated 3/14/46 . She completes a mission and Howard Stark is about to kick off shield with Peggy running it.Howard loved Peggy so Flynn being a jerk to Peggy and Howard being Flynn's boss at that time explains Flynn's Sudden absence. Fired.Mar 46 is one year from Steve Rogers going missing in Mar45. A month later Howard becomes wanted for treason. No more shield talk for now because Howard might be a traitor.The Zodiac she retrieved on the her mission becomes a focal point in an episode of agents of shield over 70 years later. The very first episode of the TV series show her flashing back to the month before, the night of the Zodiac mission 3/15/46
It's should be placed behind Captain America the First Avenger and ahead of both seasons of the TV show

Comment: Could you [edit] in some evidence to back this up?